# How to specify which __init__ should be called based on the parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, uml

So I recently started learning python and right now I am stuck with a task where I am supposed to implement a UML Diagram.
It looks like this:

[image: UML Diagram]

It's basically modelling person, adult, children and a retired person. Now the part where I am stuck is that the task is that one parameter which says "alter" (eng. = age) defines which class should be initialized. A Person who is below 18 years (alter < 18) is a Kind (eng. = child). A Person between 18 and 61 is an Erwachsener (eng. = adult) and everything above is a Pensionierter (eng. = retired person).

Now my problem is that I don't know how to implement that distinguishment...

Here is what I have so far:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, male, alter):
        self.name = name
        self.male = male
        self.__alter = alter

    def print_beschreibung(self):
        if self.male:
            print("Ich heiße " + self.name + ", bin männlich,", self.__alter, "Jahre alt")
        else:
            print("Ich heiße " + self.name +  ", bin weiblich,", self.__alter, "Jahre alt")    

    def get_alter(self):
        return self.__alter    

    def set_alter(self, neues_alter):
        self.__alter = neues_alter

class Erwachsener(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, male, alter, lohn, ist_verheiratet, kinder):
        super().__init__(name, male, alter)
        self.__lohn = lohn
        self.ist_verheiratet = ist_verheiratet
        self.kinder = kinder    


peter = Person("Peter Lustig", True, 52)
peter.print_beschreibung()
```

Comment: You're saying the `Person` constructor should return an instance of the corresponding subclass depending on the age of the person? So `peter` would be an `Erwachsener`?

Comment: Yes exactly, never thought about it that way. Can a constructor have a return statement ?

Comment: But that doesn't work. You're only passing 3 arguments into the constructor: `Person("Peter Lustig", True, 52)` but the `Erwachsener` constructor expects more arguments than that: `name, male, alter, lohn, ist_verheiratet, kinder`. You'd have to call the constructor like `Person('Peter Lustig', True, 52, 12345, False, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to implement this behavior. The simplest is to have a class `_Person` which is the same as your current `Person` class:

```
class _Person:
    def __init__(self, name, male, alter):
        self.name = name
        self.male = male
        self.__alter = alter

    def print_beschreibung(self):
        if self.male:
            print("Ich heiße " + self.name + ", bin männlich,", self.__alter, "Jahre alt")
        else:
            print("Ich heiße " + self.name + ", bin weiblich,", self.__alter, "Jahre alt")

    def get_alter(self):
        return self.__alter

    def set_alter(self, neues_alter):
        self.__alter = neues_alter


class Kind(_Person):
    pass


class Erwachsener(_Person):
    def __init__(self, name, male, alter, lohn, ist_verheiratet, kinder):
        super().__init__(name, male, alter)
        self.__lohn = lohn
        self.ist_verheiratet = ist_verheiratet
        self.kinder = kinder


class Pensionierter(_Person):
    pass
```

Then you have a function `Person` which behaves like a class and returns a corresponding `Erwachsener`, `Kind` or `Pensionierter` class:

```
def Person(*args, **kwargs):
    alter = args[2]
    if alter < 18:
        return Kind(*args, **kwargs)
    elif 18 <= alter <= 61:
        return Erwachsener(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return Pensionierter(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can use this function like this:

```
peter = Person("Peter Lustig", True, 52, 0, False, 0)
print(isinstance(peter, Erwachsener))
peter.print_beschreibung()
```

If you want `Person` to be a class, you are going to have to do some magic:

```
class Person:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        alter = args[2]
        if alter < 18:
            cls = Kind
        elif alter < 61:
            cls = Erwachsener
        else:
            cls = Pensionierter
        return object.__new__(cls)
     # The rest of the class
```

Then you can use it as above:

```
peter = Person("Peter Lustig", True, 52,0,False,0)
print(isinstance(peter, Erwachsener)) # prints True
peter.print_beschreibung()
```

But you can also to thing like this:

```
print(isinstance(peter, Person)) # prints True
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of this solution. People would think that `Person` is a class even though it's not. If someone tries to use it like `isinstance(peter, Person)`, they'll get an error. I think it would be better to incorporate this functionality into the class instead of exporting it into a separate function.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Fair point. But I don't mind the logic of this answer. I'd keep the original `Person` class and have a `make_person` factory function so it's clear from the name that it's not a class. But I'm also interested in seeing alternative solutions.

Comment: Personally, I'd implement it as a `Person.from_age` classmethod.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I added another suggestion. Is that better?

Comment: Yeah, I think the `__new__` solution is fine in this case. Generally speaking it can be confusing if a constructor returns an instance of a subclass, but in this case I think it's acceptable because `Person` looks like an abstract class.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think i got the idea behind your solution.